# Kotlin: function to stop iteration when predicate satisfied

Tags: kotlin, built-in

I'm looking for a function in Kotlin which stops an iteration once a predicate is fulfilled:

```
val services = listOf(service1, service2)
...
var res: Result = null
services.stopIfPredicateFulFilled { service ->
    res = service.doSomething()
    res != null
}
```

While this example is not really nice since `res` is overwritten in each iteration I hope the intention is clear.
`forEach` doesn't do the job the way I expect it to be done. So, I was wondering if there isn't anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functions [`find { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/find.html) and [`firstOrNull { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-or-null.html) (they are equivalent, just named differently). They find the first element satisfying the predicate and return that element, ignoring all the remaining elements.

```
services.find { service ->
    res = service.doSomething()
    res != null
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks, I guess there's no function which returns `res` immediately after success?

Comment: @christianmeyer, there's no such function indeed. You can, however, work with lazily evaluated sequences and get the desired behavior by using the combination of `.asSequence().mapNotNull { ... }.firstNotNull()`, returning `null` from the lambda unless it found the desired result.